# Best way to pass nullable values to functions

Tags: android, kotlin, null

I have pretty common piece of kotlin code here:

```
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            val geoCoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())

            val addr = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1)

            Toast.makeText(this, "Got location info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            locationText.text = addr.get(0).toString()
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception ->
            locationText.text = exception.message
        }
```

Since the location value from the callback can be `null` in certain cases we have to define it as a `nullable` type like so `location: Location?`. The problem arises when I want to use the latitude and longitude attributes from the location object like `location.longitude`. The compiler gives the following error:

`Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted calls are allowed on nullable reciever of type Locaion?`

Now I know doing `location!!.latitude` is a dangerous thing because it claims the value to not be null. And using `location?.latitude` gives me a type mismatch `Required: Double Found: Double?`

I've seen this happening many times while making async calls. My question is what is the official "kotin" way to handle situations like these?

Comment: I think it is not kotlin problem. different point with java is that kotlin force you check nullabliliy. so, you have to add null-check or use elvis operator. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin, unlike Java and many other languages, requires that you explicitly identify a nullable value as nullable or it will throw up a compiler error (as you've discovered). This is done to prevent the dreaded NullPointerException, an effect of the so-called [billion dollar mistake](https://medium.com/@hinchman_amanda/null-pointer-references-the-billion-dollar-mistake-1e616534d485) (programmers the world over forgetting to check for null before assuming a variable's value is not null, and causing a NPE).

There are three ways to go about handling what you're asking about in Kotlin, and it boils down to a stylistic preference on your part plus a bit about how much code is conditioned upon the null/non-null status of the value. The methods all incorporate a null check.

For purposes of this answer, I'll assume if the latitude property is null, you want to throw an error. But one great thing about explicit nullability in Kotlin is it forces you to think about how you actually want to handle null values (is it an error that halts your code? do you plug in a default value and continue your code? etc.)

First, you can use the traditional `if/else`. For personal aesthetic reasons, I tend not to use this in Kotlin. I just enjoy using the other methods because they're "new" to me, coming from C-like languages, where if/else is old hat.

```
val myVal: Location? = someValue

if(myVal == null) {
   throw IllegalStateException("myVal is null")
} else {
   /* handle the non-null case(s) */
}
```

Second, you can use one of the Kotlin [scoping functions](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) (they are all used in subtly different ways but are interchangeable for the purposes of your question).

`myValue.let` tells Kotlin to stick `myValue` into the following code block but renamed to `it`. But `myValue?.let` tells Kotlin to do this *only if myValue is non-null*. If myValue is null, the block of code following `let` will not execute. If you put a `?:` and some code after the block of code, that will be run if myValue is null:

```
val myVal: Location? = someValue

myVal?.let { location ->
   /* handle the non-null case */
} ?: throw IllegalStateException("myVal is null")
```

In the above, `throw ...` only executes if myVal is null. If myVal is non-null, it will not throw.

The third option is similar to the second:

```
val myVal: Location? = someValue

myVal ?: throw IllegalStateException("myVal is null")

/* now handle the non-null case */
```

Remember the `?:` from above? That's it again, and it operates the same way: if `myVal` is null, it will execute what comes to the right of it. In this case, a throw. If this were in a function, you could also do `myVal ?: return someDefaultValue` for example.

It operates as a type guard and ensures that for any subsequent code, myVal *cannot* be null (because myVal is immutable and we've now determined it's not null).

Answer (score 0):

For nullable variable you need to check first variable is not null.

You can do using below methods:

```
if(location != null){
   val latitude = location.latitude
}

or 

location?.let{
   val latitude = it.latitude // location can be replace with **it**
}
```